# Jquery image and navigation swap?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to recreate the function on this page.

When you swop the shoe color you get alternate views on that show.

How does it work?

http://www.clae.com/Product.aspx?l=00010000000000000000&p=CLA01253

Comment: why don't you view the source code of the page and take a look yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The example below will load image1 by default. It will load up a new image for for the image that is clicked on and replace the one in the image with the id of main.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#img1, #img2').click(function() {
                                $('#main').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
                        });
                });

        </script>
        <img id="main" src="image1.png"/>

        <br> <br>
        <img id="img1" src="image1.jpg"/>

        <img id="img2" src="image2.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is very lightweight MrCrapper. That works the images perfectly but how do you change the view menu for that particular shoe color? The view options appear for the color of shoe you have selected.

Comment: So your talking about the options to change the 3 different views under the shoe (which in turn are three different images for that color)?